# query data base with integer clause?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

how can i query database with integer clause .i want delete query using integer clause .(i want like this:-"delete table_name where name=myname And id=integer value") i have less knowledge about database query please help me.

this is my database:

```
public class ContactDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="totalContact.db";
    public static final  String TABLE_NAME="mecontact";
    public static final  String NAME="name";
    public static final  String PHONE="phone";


    public ContactDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL("create table mecontact" +
                    "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, phone text)");
        }catch(android.database.SQLException e){
                System.out.println("table create nhi ho rha");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mecontact");
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void insertContact(String nam,String mob){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put(NAME,nam);
        contentValues.put(PHONE,mob);

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteContact(String d,int pos){
        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"name='"+d+"' AND /*what is for _id column*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: **WARNING**: You're injecting `d` without any [escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/java.html) which has created an [injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) here. Be careful about this.

Answer (score 0):

For integer values, just put them into the SQL string.
(For strings, you should use parameters instead.)

```
db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "name = ? AND _id = " + pos,
          new String[]{ d });
```